# Reading the contents of Clipboard in FF

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, clipboard

I am able to do that in IE, but FF doesn't allow to do something like:

```
$("#txtBox").bind('paste', function (e) {
        alert('pasting text!!!!');           
        alert(window.clipboardData.getData("Text"));
        window.event.returnValue = false;


    });
```

I am required to trap the clipboard contents onpaste, then populate a table with this content. We are allowing people to copy and paste from Excel.

What are some of the ways that are being used to achieve this in FF?
Thanks

Comment: You could have the user paste the text into a textarae or editable div, and then you can parse the text on the page. This gets around having to work with the clipboard.

Comment: this might be a good solution:) I personally would do it like that, thanks. But ultimately it's not up to me.

Answer (score 4):

For the security reasons, you can't manipulate clipboard contents from JavaScript in Firefox.

If reading and writing clipboard contents is mandatory for your application, you may want to use Silverlight or Flash instead, or another RIA solutions (don't know if other solutions allow to manipulate clipboard).

Comment: Flash does clipboards too fwiw.